# How can I switch scenes in SceneKit when clicking a SpriteKit overlay label?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am stuck on this problem.

I laid a SpriteKit node over a SceneKit Scene. I'm trying to 
use SpriteKit to display labels and those labels switch scenes when touched. Imagine "Game Start", "Quit", "Shop" as buttons.

But it doesn't work.

How should I switch scenes in SceneKit from interaction with SpriteKit labels?

[GameStart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOjjt.jpg)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let touchNode:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if(touchNode.name == "elementButton"){
            //let scene = ElementsScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene)
        } else if (touchNode.name == "classicButton"){
            //let scene = ClassicScene(size: self.size)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene)
        } else if (touchNode.name == "quitButton"){
            //Quit Game
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The API for scene transition is the following (ObjC version):

```
- (void)presentScene:(SCNScene *)scene withTransition:(SKTransition *)transition incomingPointOfView:(nullable SCNNode *)pointOfView completionHandler:(nullable void (^)())completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
```

"presentScene" with just one argument doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much! Happy Thanksgiving!